# Wait Issue in Backgroung Jobs of "powershell_script" Resource

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra, wait, rdp

I am trying to run  a powershell_script in a Chef Recipe which runs some jobs in background. I need to wait until all background jobs are finished and restart the machine after 1 second. Here's what I am doing:

```
   ruby 'restart_module' do
     code <<-EOH
       system('shutdown.exe -r -f -t 1')        
     EOH
     action :nothing
   end

   powershell_script 'Adding RDS roles' do
     code <<-EOH 
     Start-Job -Name addRolesFeatures -ScriptBlock {
       Add-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-RD-Server
       Add-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-Licensing
       Add-WindowsFeature -Name RSAT-RDS-Licensing-Diagnosis-UI
       Add-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-Licensing-UI
     }
     Wait-Job -Name addRolesFeatures
     EOH
     notifies :run, 'ruby[restart_module]', :immediately
  end
```

However, when machine restarts, RDS-RD-Server is still not installed, remaining features are. 
Am I missing something while waiting for background job to finish?

Note: I can not use Restart option of Add-WindowsFeature cmdlet. Instead I am using a delayed force restart to tell my workstation exactly before chef-node is going to be restarted (assuming no jobs are pending at this point).

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the standard `windows_feature` and `restart` resources?

Comment: I have tried using windows_feature resource as well, but problem with that is it also installs in background. i.e. next resource is ran before before previous feature is fully installed. I need to wait for the installation to complete before moving on.